# Смена цвета при нажатии

Tags: html, css

```css
.test {
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
  background:#000;
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

Как сделать так, чтобы при клике на блок "test", он становился красным, при еще одном клике - обратно на черный.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно сделать на html+css

```css
.test {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: black;
}
input {
  display: none;
}
input:checked + label > div {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="colorbox">
<label for="colorbox">
  <div class="test"></div>
</label>
```

Answer (score 3):

Можно воспользоваться [родственным селектором `~`](https://webref.ru/css/selector/sibling) и связью [`<label>`](https://webref.ru/html/label) с [`<input>`](https://webref.ru/html/input).

**Плюсы**: javascript не нужен.
**Минусы**: нужна дополнительная разметка.

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
.test {
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: #000;
}
#switcher:checked ~ .test {
  background: #f00;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="hidden" id="switcher">
<label class="test" for="switcher"></label>
```

Comment: Быстрый какой. )

Answer (score 1):

Используя javascript и jQuery:

```
$('.test').on('click', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('red');
});
```

и в css добавить

```
.test.red{
    color: red;
}
```