# Как сделать выпадающий список по клику?

Tags: html, css

Верстаю сортировку, нужно чтобы список выпадал при клике и выбирался нужный пункт. Как это сделать? Буду благодарен за помощь.

И ещё нужно чтобы он не сдвигал нижний контент.

Comment: И ещё нужно чтобы он не сдвигал нижний контент.

Comment: сделайте выпадающий список на html, в нем есть встроенная функция выбора нужного элемента, а чтобы не сдвигал добавьте этому списку `position:absolute`. А если хотите чтобы вам ответили хорошо, то ваш вопрос не должен выглядеть как ТЗ на фрилансе, нужны примеры кода, а также хоть какие-то попытки от вас в поисках нужного решения.

Comment: На html + css можно сделать только на hover вроде как, а мне нужно что при клике раскрывался..

Comment: Не нужен javascript. Посмотрите этот ответ: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/553585/13336

Comment: VenZell а если меню генерируется на php ?

Comment: Стилизация меню никак не зависит от того, как оно генерируется. Вы можете хоть на HTML написать необходимую разметку, хоть в jade, хоть на php сгенерировать.

Comment: а если список 3 вложенности ?